# std::cin.getline( ) vs. std::cin

Tags: c++, getline, cin

When should `std::cin.getline()` be used? What does it differ from `std::cin`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In case with char*, [`std::cin.getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) getting line, instead of `std::cin` getting first word.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. `std::cin` doesn't get anything; it's just an object. You have to do something with it (e.g. call a member function like `get`) before it does anything.

Comment: `char s1[256], s2[256]; std::cin >> s1; cin.getline(s2, 256);`

Comment: `std::cin >> s1` is a call to a global function `istream& operator>> (istream&, char*)`

Comment: This answer needs to be edited. The wording and explanation are confusing

Answer (score 47):

Let's take `std::cin.getline()` apart. First, there's `std::`. This is the namespace in which the standard library lives. It has hundreds of types, functions and objects.

`std::cin` is such an object. It's the standard character input object, defined in `<iostream>`. It has some methods of its own, but you can also use it with many free functions. Most of these methods and functions are ways to get one or more characters from the standard input.

Finally, `.getline()` is one such method of `std::cin` (and other similar objects). You tell it how many characters it should get from the object on its left side (`std::cin` here), and where to put those characters. The precise number of characters can vary: `.getline()`  will stop in three cases:
1. The end of a line is reached
2. There are no characters left in the input (doesn't happen normally on `std::cin` as you can keep typing)
3. The maximum number of characters is read.

There are other methods and functions that can be used with the `std::cin` object, e.g.

```
  std::string s;
  int i;
  std::cin >> s; // Read a single word from std::cin
  std::cin >> i; // Read a single number from std::cin
  std::getline(std::cin, s); // Read an entire line (up to \n) from std::cin
  std::cin.ignore(100); // Ignore the next 100 characters of std::cin
```

Answer (score 10):

Did you read any documentation (e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)?

Basically, `std::cin` (or more generally, any `std::istream`) is used directly in order to obtain formatted input, e.g. `int x; std::cin >> x;`.  `std::cin.getline()` is used simply to fill a raw `char *` buffer.

Comment: the member getline doesn't get you a `std::string`, it's used for filling a `char*` buffer. The getline that gets you a `std::string` is the free function `std::getline`.

Comment: @Oli. Yes, I saw the documentation for a bit but didn't get the idea. Now, I think it is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

(Very simplefied)My answer is, that `std :: cin.getline()` can contain spaces, while `std :: cin >>` can not.

Comment: It seems to be a good for a simple example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As already others have answered (even better) roughly speaking, use `getline()` to read an entire line (i.e., a string terminating with `\n`) and `cin>>var` to read a number compatible with the type of `var` (integer, float, double etc.) or a single word.

In this answer I want to emphasize a problem that arises when mixing the two methods. When you do:

```
int a;
string s;
cin>>a;
getline(cin, s)
```

`cin` leaves an end of line, `\n`, character which is then read by `getline();`. It is possible to overcome this problem by using `cin.ignore()`.

```
int a;
string s;
cin>>a;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, s)
```

Comment: `cin.ignore()` will only discard a single character, whereas `cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );` will discard the rest of the line, including the newline character. It doesn't seem meaningful to use `cin.ignore()` in this case, because `cin>>a` will only read a single word. Therefore, you cannot assume that the next character will be the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

The use of std::cin >> std::ws skips the whitespace, in particular the newline, and carries on reading where the actual content is entered.

```
int a;
string s;
cin>>a;
getline(cin>>ws, s)
```

Comment: int a;
string s;
cin>>a;
getline(cin>>ws, s)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).