# how to open a file by its full path given by user?

Tags: c++, file

I have written this code. I want to ask from user the full path of a file and then go to that path and open file. But unfortunately the program cannot find the file. for excample I have created a file in this path G:\project 2\newfile but when I type this in the c++ console it says that "Error while opening the file". I really need to solve this problem. please help me with this. thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string address;
    cout << "Enter the full path of the file" << endl;
    cin >> address;
    ifstream file(address.c_str());

    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error while opening the file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you debugged whether `address` contains correct information after your input?

Comment: Works fine on my machine...

Answer (score 5):

Your application is failing because you aren't properly handling spaces in the filename.

Try this instead of `cin >> address;`:

```
getline(cin,address);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745858/stdcin-getline-vs-stdcin) question for the difference between `cin` and `getline`.