# How to randomly display an user input string using c++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, dev-c++

I am trying to randomly display a user input string using c++ but I couldn't find a way to do. 
  Currently I am pre defining some strings

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
 srand(time(0));
 const string wordlist[4] = {"hi","hello","what's up","wassup"};
 string word = wordlist [rand()%4];
 cout<<word;
 return 0;
}
```

**What I want is:-** I don't want to pre define them. I want the user to type in 4 words and I will display a word from the 4 words given by the user (randomly).

Comment: `stand(time(0));` ? Some examples of using `std::cin` should right next to the examples for using `std::cout` in your favourite [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `stand(time(0));` What's that function? Did you mean `srand()`?

Comment: What are you actually struggling with? You seem to know how to randomly pick an index in array, is the question about getting user input?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: It's stand() sorry that was a typo.

Comment: @Kenny Just what immediately came to my mind.

Comment: Yes. Im struggling with the user input.

Comment: @JoyDey _"It's stand() sorry that was a typo"_ And you even repeated it :-D

Comment: Srand got Autocorrect.

Comment: @JoyDey _"Yes. Im struggling with the user input."_ You probably want a `std::vector<std::string>` to store user input of _words_.

Comment: If the number of strings is always going to be 4, `std::array` may be a tiny increment better than `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you will have to first remove `const` qualifier from `wordlist` array.

```
srand(time(0));
std::vector<string> wordlist(4);
for(auto& s: wordlist) std::cin>>s;
string word = wordlist [rand()%4];
cout<<word;
```

- Line 3 is C++11's range based for loop, this way I can easily loop over elements of `std::vector<string>` without indices.
- If there are multiple words in a string then use `getline(cin,s)` accordingly. Then input each string in a new line. But be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316564/mixing-cin-and-getline-input-issues) when mixing `cin` and `getline` for taking input.
- You can use `std::array` if the size is going to be fixed (i.e. 4) as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Doesn't look like a right approach to read the `wordlist` from user input in 1st place.

Comment: Got an error. Range based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Comment: That is not a good approach and it is not a good answer for someone kind of new. LOL

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hmm... Looks like it would work (at least to a degree)?

Comment: @M.K Is there something I should clarify more?

Comment: @madhur4127 it's working now after adding a compiler flag

Comment: @JoyDey Prior to C++11, you can use a standard `for` loop with an index: `for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) std::cin >> wordlist[i];`

Comment: @SergeyA, when do you think it will fail?

Comment: @madhur4127 well, the results might be unexpected if you enter several words on the line.

Comment: @SergeyA, I think this is covered in bullet 2 of the answer.

Comment: @madhur4127 those words were not there when I made my comment.

Comment: `for(auto& s: wordlist)` this is not definetly a loop type for a beginner @madhur4127

Comment: @M.K Disagree. Range-based for is a lot harder to mess up if you are accessing the container end-to-end.

Comment: Agreed, but a lot harder to understand. @user4581301