# C++ - Read and write csv files by including their path in console

Tags: c++, csv, path, console

I want to read and write csv files using C++.
The constraint is that I have to write the path in the console.
For example, if I want to read a file, I have to write in the console :
`Read "filePath"`
And if I want to write a file : 
`Write "filePath" "delimiter"`
I have made functions that work, but without indicating the path in the console.

Here is my main function :

```
int main()
{
    SudokuGrid sudokuGrid;
    bool done = false;
    string command;
    while (!done) {
        cout << "Enter a command :" << endl;
        cin >> command;
        if (command == "Read") {
            sudokuGrid.readGridFromCSVFile("Sudoku.csv");
            cout << endl << "Grid read with success !" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (command == "Write") {
            sudokuGrid.writeCSVFileFromGrid("Sudoku3.csv", *";");
            cout << endl << "The file has been created !" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (command == "Display") {
            cout << "Here is the grid !" << endl << endl;
            sudokuGrid.printGrid();
        }
        else if (command == "Exit") {
            done = true;
        }
        else if (command == "Help") {
            cout << "TODO" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect Command" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

It works but my problem is that I write the file path directly in the main function, but I want to be able to write it in the console.

I have tried :

```
cin >> command >> csvFilePath;
if (command == "Read") {
    sudokuGrid.readGridFromCSVFile(csvFilePath);
    cout << endl << "Grid read with success !" << endl << endl;
    sudokuGrid.printGrid();
}
```

It works but only with two inputs (the command "Read" and the file path) but I also want to be able to do it with one input (Display) or three inputs (Write, file path and delimiter)

Comment: Hi ! As SO is not a code provider service but a Q&A plateform about specific problems, you should add what you have tried and done to attempt to solve your problem. Also try to add a [minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you have any doubt on how to improve your question, you may also check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In your case, if you already made functions that work, providing them and explaining why you don't manage to call them using console may lead to more and faster useful answers

Comment: Congrats, you now have a fully answerable and complete question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::getline()` ([doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)) instead of `std::cin` + `operator>>`.

This way you will be able to get the whole entered command in a string, no matter how many arguments you give. Then you can [split your string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266139/11502610) and store each argument in a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```cpp
SudokuGrid sudokuGrid;
bool done = false;
std::string command;
while (!done) {
    cout << "Enter a command :" << endl;     
    std::getline(std::cin, command); // Get the whole command, with arguments

    // Spliting string using Vincenzo Pii answer in given link
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
    while ((pos = command.find(" ")) != std::string::npos) { // this loop destroy command and split it into arguments
        arguments.push_back(command.substr(0, pos)); 
        command.erase(0, pos + 1); // 1 is the size of the delimiter entered in find
    }
    arguments.push_back(command);
```

Your command would then be the first string of your vector, allowing you to keep your if-else conditions and deal with arguments in them.
For exemple for "Read" condition, you will now have :

```
if (arguments.at(0) == "Read") {
    sudokuGrid.readGridFromCSVFile(arguments.at(1));
    cout << endl << "Grid read with success !" << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: By the way, as I used getline, make sure you don't use `std::cin` or else make sure you deal with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316564/mixing-cin-and-getline-input-issues)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it raises an exception std::out_of_range on the line : if (arguments.at(0) == "Read")

Comment: @CongelateurSama What was the input  ?

Comment: Read C:\\Users\\Hugo\\Desktop\\Sudoku.csv
or Read "C:\\Users\\Hugo\\Desktop\\Sudoku.csv"

Comment: @CongelateurSama Strange I don't manage to reproduce, make sure that `arguments` is in the right scope. Your if-else conditions still have to be in the `while(!done)` loop. Maybe try to use a debugger to check if `command` and `arguments` are correctly set. Also keep in mind that I kept `std`s because I didn't use namespace. If you do used `namespace std`, you may need to remove them

Comment: @CongelateurSama Which C++ standard do you use ? (C++11?14?17?) I think that operator `==` doesn't exist for `std::string`s until C++17. You should have a go with `arguments.at(0).compare("Read") == 0` instead

Comment: I use the latest C++ standard (C++17). I tried ```arguments.at(0).compare("Read") == 0``` and I got the same exception.

Comment: Erf, once again I don't manage to reproduce, try to control `command` and `arguments` values with a debugger. Probably unrelated with the exception but you may need to add `push_back(command);` after the while loop to get the last argument too, see edit

Comment: It finally worked with the addition of ```push_back(command);```
Thank you so much !

Comment: No problem, this is the purpose of SO ! Keep in mind that you can (and should) accept an answer that worked for you, letting everyone know that this answer is a workaround for your problem, which help for referencing and may help fellow users who have similar problem

Comment: Thank you for your advices about SO too !