# I am just trying to use the getline function as an absolute beginner. I still dont know what went wrong here

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

constexpr auto MAX_NUM_LEN = 10;

int main() {
    string a_num[MAX_NUM_LEN];

    cout << "Type your full ID" << endl;
    cin.getline(a_num, MAX_NUM_LEN, '.');

    cout << "\nyour input is: " << a_num;
}
```

Link to my embedded image of the program i did in VS code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM7BC.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include whatever error you're getting as text, not as an image.

Comment: `a_num` is an array of `string`s, but `getline()` expects an array of `char`s (actually a pointer to it).

Comment: See [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) compared to [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The first expects a character array (or allocated block), the second expects a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `char a_num[MAX_NUM_LEN];` instead of `string a_num[MAX_NUM_LEN];`

Your code will run.

when you use `cin.getline()` function, then its first parameters would be either a constant character pointer or a character array name.

Please check following resources to learn more about `getline`

- [std::getline (string)](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
- [getline (string) in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getline-string-c/)
- [C++ program to read string using cin.getline()](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/cpp-program-to-read-string-using-cin-getline)
- [std::cin.getline( ) vs. std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745858/stdcin-getline-vs-stdcin)