# How do I remove the extra space on the output from this method

Tags: c++, class, vector, data-structures

I'm trying to solve this question below:

> Write code to read a list of song durations and song names from input. For each line of input, set the duration and name of newSong. Then add newSong to playlist. Input first receives a song duration, then the name of that song (which you can assume is only one word long).
>
> Input example:
>
> ```
> 424 Time
> 383 Money
> -1
> ```

This is the code that I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Song {
public:
    void SetDurationAndName(int songDuration, string songName) {
        duration = songDuration;
        name = songName;
    }

    void PrintSong() const {
        cout << duration << " - " << name << endl;
    }

    int GetDuration() const { return duration; }

    string GetName() const { return name; }

private:
    int duration;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    vector<Song> playlist;
    Song newSong;
    int songDuration;
    string songName;
    unsigned int i;

    cin >> songDuration;
    while (songDuration >= 0) {
     /* Solution is below */

        getline(cin, songName);
        newSong.SetDurationAndName(songDuration, songName);
        playlist.push_back(newSong);
           /* Solution is above */

         cin >> songDuration;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < playlist.size(); ++i) {
        newSong = playlist.at(i);
        newSong.PrintSong();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the message I get when I try to run my code:

[image: Message from running the code]

Can someone please help me remove the extra space from the method? I don't know how to remove this space, I tried everything I know.

Comment: Suggestion: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)

Comment: Links rot and otherwise may not be accessible when needed. Don't use them for important information like a code example.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: There are no tools in C++ streams to remove a character once written--in many cases it won't even be possible because the stream flushed and the data has been sent--so generally when you have an extra space in your output the best thing to do is not write it in the first place.

Comment: GDBOnline is a debugger. Use it to step through you code and see exactly how the space got there. Then stop doing that.

Comment: Any reason you are using getline inside the while loop? try substituting it with std::cin

Comment: std::getline can contain spaces, while std::cin can not.
[check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745858/stdcin-getline-vs-stdcin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this statement:

```
cin >> songDuration;
```

Reading stops when a non-digit character is encountered, such as the whitespace following the number. The whitespace is left in the input buffer for subsequent reading.

Then this statement:

```
getline(cin, songName);
```

Reads from the input buffer until a line break is encountered. As such, the whitespace that is present between the number and the name ends up in the front of the `songName` variable. That is the whitespace you are seeing in your output.

The solution is to ignore the whitespace before reading the `songName`.

You can use the [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) I/O manipulator for that purpose, eg:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
getline(cin >> ws, songName);
```

However, the instructions clearly state the following about the song name:

> the name of that song (which you can assume is only one word long)

So, you can alternatively use `operator>>` to read in the `songName`. It will ignore the leading whitespace for you:

```
cin >> songName;
```